# Converting integer of tuple to string of tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I wanted to convert the integer of tuple into string of tuple.
For example:

```
data = [(2,3,4,...),(23,42,54,...),......]
```

would result in:

```
d = [('2','3','4',...),('23','42','54',....)......]
```

Please notice how tuple is big and list is also big.

I tried the code below but it doesn't give me the result I was looking for:

```
data = [(2,3,4,...),(23,42,54,...),......] 

d=[]
for t in data:
    d.append(str(t))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This gets close:

```
data = [[str(x) for x in tup] for tup in data]
```

If you actually *need* tuples:

```
data = [tuple(str(x) for x in tup) for tup in data]
```

---

Or, if you prefer a more "functional" approach:

```
data = [tuple(map(str, tup)) for tup in data]
```

Though it seems that `map` has fallen out of favor with the python crowd (or maybe it never was actually in favor ;-).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are great. I will accept this answer in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This will recursively convert infinitely nested lists and tuples:

```
def stringify(something):
    if type(something) == list:
        return [stringify(x) for x in something]
    elif type(something) == tuple:
        return tuple(stringify(list(something)))
    else:
        return str(something)
```

Comment: Careful throwing around the term "infinitely" -- You'll run into a recursion limit _sometime_, at least in most python implementations.  I'm not sure about stackless . . . Hmm . . . :-)